# Can Cocoa automatically handle contractions for localized strings in French?

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsstring

I have a localized `NSString` that is something like "You win. It was Chuck Norris.". The French translation of this is "Gagne. il s'agissait bien de Chuck Norris". But when the name starts with a vowel it should say "Gagné. il s'agissait bien d'Alfred Hitchcock".

Does `NSString` offer support for these situations or do I need to manually translate each possibility?

Comment: Just to be clear - if I understand correctly, it is not as much the gender that is the issue here as the rules for the use of an apostrophe and contraction that are in play here, right? (as in " d' " versus " de ")

Comment: Correct, @Monolo: this isn't a grammatical gender issue, it's a contraction issue. There's a lot of overlap between the two, however.

Comment: Yes you are more correct @Monolo. When the noun isn't a person, but an object apparently the gender becomes an issue and you can get other combinations with du etc. etc. It seems this is never going to work so we are changing the translations.

Comment: If you can, watch the WWDC 2012 sessions about localization. There's good stuff there. I believe the sessions are up on ADC/iTunes for developers.

Comment: Please take a look at https://github.com/tr8n/tr8n_objc_clientsdk It provides a mechanism for defining Language Context Rules and Language Cases. Disclosure: I am the creator and maintainer of that library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to do localization using tools like `NSLocalizedString()`, variations like this are going to occur in a lot of languages (especially those with grammatical genders) and are a lot of trouble to deal with. There's no inbuilt change-strings-if-starting-with-a-vowel method, but something like this would be necessary (pseudo-code):

```
if (language == LANG_FRENCH) {
    if (myName.startsWith(ANY_VOWEL)) {
        result = format(@"Gagné ... d'%@", myName);
    } else {
        result = format(@"Gagné ... de %@", myName);
    }
}
```

**Why did I give you pseudo-code instead of real code?** Because this is the *wrong way* to do this work. It's messy, it's ugly, and there are a lot of edge cases. For instance, the letter "H" in French can be "aspirated" or "non-aspirated", and one takes "l'/d'" while the other takes "le/la/de" (compare "l'hôtel" and "le hockey".) The distinction is arbitrary and *cannot* be determined solely by examining the spelling of the word.

Rather than attempting to match your format string to the name, try to change the format string to be neutral. Instead of `"Il s'agissait bien d'%@."`, try `"Le nom? C'est %@!"` so that the gender and spelling of the name do not affect the localization. Different languages will have different options here.

Comment: Yes I asked the french person next to me and he said, "Just change it for aeiou, no problem. Oh wait, there is y and h too. Hrmmm.". I give up, we'll change the sentence. Your answer was spot on.

Comment: I'm Canadian, so I speak French. Localization to/from French/English is common here--you learn a few tricks if you're doing your job right. ;)

Comment: Absolutely. Note that if you put the format string ("You win. It was %@") in the localizable.strings with a clear comment, the sort of creative localization that Jonathan suggests can be done by an experienced localizer, without you even knowing about it (if you're lucky to have a smart, caring localizer... given the low pay-per-word localization world of today, it might be rare)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at https://github.com/tr8n/tr8n_objc_clientsdk

It provides support for Language Context Rules and Language Cases.

In your example, you would localize the English string using the following macro:

```
Tr8nLocalizedStringWithTokens(
    @"You win. It was {name}.", 
    @{"name": @"Chuck Norris"}
);
```

{name} is a data token.

The translation in French would use a language case, like the following:

```
"You win. It was {name}." = "Gagne. Il s'agissait bien {name::d_de}"
```

Where (::d_de) is defined as Tr8n's language case rule, as follows:

```
if (match "/^[aeiouAEIOU]/" @value) 
then (prepend "d'" @value) 
else (prepend "de " @value)
```

If you ever need it as capital, use:

```
{name::D_De}
```

Also, if you need to make the name bold, use Attributed String macro, as follows:

```
Tr8nLocalizedAttributedStringWithTokens(
      @"You win. It was [bold: {name}].", 
      @{
         @"name": @"Chuck Norris", 
         @"bold": @{@"font": @{@"style": @"bold"}}
      }
);
```

Translation to French would be:

```
"You win. It was [bold: {name}]." = "Gagne. Il s'agissait bien [bold: {name::d_de}]"
```

Btw, gender dependencies are also fully supported. Let me know the case and I will show you how to use them.

Disclosure: I am the creator and maintainer of that library. If you notice that some rules are missing for any language, please let me know and I would gladly add them.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please add the relevant information from the link. Otherwise your answer is deemed to be deleted.