# NSLocalizedString special cases

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm doing some localization work in my app. There are some special cases, for instance in the swedish language of the genitive form.

If a word ends with s you should not add an s to the word. So for instance if I was to write the birthday of a person with last name ending with a s it would be **"Carl Fabrizius birthday"**

So as you can understand there are some logic rules to apply depending on the language, if it's swedish or english. How would I deal with this in Objective-C?

I'm thinking pseudo code it would look like this:

```
if (current locale == swedish) {
    swedishGenitiveForm();
} else if (current locale == english) {
    englishGenitiveForm();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide exact example of English and Swedish cases to see the actual differences? Also, the pseudo code is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, these [language rules are difficult to deal with programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207860/can-cocoa-automatically-handle-contractions-for-localized-strings-in-french). It is better if you  can modify the strings at the translation level. If that fails then you can apply some rules like you are suggesting but be aware that the logic grows and grows and grows..